# Print duplex from two LocalReports

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to print an ID card and I have 2 reports for two sides of the card. I want to print both sides of the card in 1 click (print duplex in 1 click),
but how should I send 2 local reports to 1 print dialog?

I'm using RDCL reports, the default visual studio report. This is my code for sending my info to LocalReports (data sets to reports).

```
dt = bl.card(p1.CodeMeli);
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1",dt);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);           
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
reportViewer2.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
this.reportViewer2.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;

dt = bl.barcode(p1.CodeMeli);
ReportDataSource rds0 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", dt);


reportViewer2.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds0);
this.reportViewer2.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
this.reportViewer2.RefreshReport();
```